# How does jemands decline in genitive form?

Tags: pronoun, genitive

> Ich habe jemands Mütze im Schuppen gefunden.

How does *jemands* decline in genitive form?

Comment: The _jemands_ IS already in genitive case, as you can see [here](http://canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-jemand3.html). Maybe that is, why you did not find it during your previous research? Or am I getting your question wrong?

Comment: yes sir you are right. jemands is already in genetive case.. but my concern sir is how does "jemand" declined in genetive case which is jemands. die Mütze is fimale, im is the combination of in dem, dee Schuppen is male.. it became im Schuppen because of the dative preposition IN. tnx for the answers sir.

Comment: I am sorry, but I still do not get, what exactly you want to know. You seem to understand that "jemand" was declined to genitive case here, and that the genitive case can be spelled as "jemandes" or "jemands". Are you asking, _why_ the genitive case is used in this example? Do you understand the meaning of this sentence?

Comment: The fact that Mütze is female doesn't play a role. "Jemand" is a pronoun (someone), not an adjective. Just like in English: *someone* --> *someone's*.

Comment: It seems that you have been helped, which is good. But since it is still not clear what your original problem was, it is very unlikely that this question will help anyone else, which is sad.

Answer (score 2):

According to the "Zweifelsfallduden" (Duden 9, 8<sup>th</sup> edition) there are two genitives of the indefinite pronoun [*jemand*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/jemand), i.e., *jemands* and *jemand**e**s*. The latter is the recommended form, and it is also used [more often](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jemands%2C%20jemandes&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cjemands%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bjemands%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BJemands%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cjemandes%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bjemandes%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BJemandes%3B%2Cc0).

I surmise, without proof, that the form *jemands* is more recent and has arisen from *jemand's*, where the [apostrophe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostroph#Verwendung_im_Deutschen) indicates that the ***e*** in the original form *jemand**e**s* was omitted. Maybe, over time, this apostrophe was simply omitted itself. In summary, the following three forms are correct:

> Ich habe *jemand**e**s* Mütze im Schuppen gefunden.
>   
>   Ich habe *jemand's* Mütze im Schuppen gefunden.
>   
>   Ich habe *jemands* Mütze im Schuppen gefunden.

For in a comment you remarked that it should sound more colloquially, I would recommend to use the indefinire article *eine* (or shortened *'ne*) rather than *jemands*:

> Ich hab' 'ne Mütze im Schuppen gefunden.

Notice again the use of apostrophes to indicate omitted letters.

Comment: thank you for the answer sir... E is not indicated in the word jemands because i used the colloquial form sir..

Comment: According to [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/jemand), jemands without the _e_ is correct as well. They state: "Genitiv jemand[e]s"

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Die Form mit _e_  scheint auch häufiger verwendet zu werden ([Ngram-Link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jemands%2C+jemandes&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cjemands%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bjemands%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BJemands%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cjemandes%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bjemandes%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BJemandes%3B%2Cc0))

Comment: i already figured out why it was decline at genetive case sir.. because someone's cup or jemands Mütze auf deutsch shows possession.. it means if it shows possession it will fall in the genetive case.. thank you

Comment: @albert If you found an answer to your question, you are allowed and encouraged to write (and accept) an answer to your own question.

Comment: Pleaes check again for your recommendation of "'ne". I think the apostrophe should be used only when omitting one letter, not when omitting several.

Answer (score 1):

It was decline at genetive case, because someone's cup or jemands Mütze auf deutsch shows possession.. it means if it shows possession it will fall under the genetive.

Comment: He albert, in case you don't know yet: you can mark one answer as "accepted" if it answers your question by clicking the check-mark next to the up- and down arrows.

Comment: When reading this answer, I guess your actual question was "Why?" and not "How?", as suggested by Carsten S and Björn Friedrich in their comments. If that is correct, could you please update your question by editing it? As it is, it is still unclear and might get closed.

Answer (score 0):

The crucial spot may also be located at the beginning of the word.

> Ich habe **J**emands Mütze im Schuppen gefunden.

The name of some people is »Jemand« as you can see here: https://www.dastelefonbuch.de/Personen/Jemand

In this case the genitive gets built without the final »e«.